# Javascript "break" always hits

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, break

I feel like I'm missing something very basic here. Why doesn't my attached code get to the else statement? It seems to be something with the break statement. This is probably something really simple that I'm just overlooking.

HTML

```
<button onclick="yo();">Hit me</button>
```

JS

```
var line = "no";

function yo() {
    if (line == "yes") {
        break;   
    }
    else {
        window.alert("hi");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dsX65/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have a *syntax error*.

`break` statement can be used in loops and `switch` statements and can't be used in `if` clause.

> **break**
>
> Terminates the current loop, switch, or label statement and transfers
>   program control to the statement following the terminated statement.

<sup>(... from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) ...)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use `return` instead of `break` and that will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use the `return` statement instead.

```
var line = "no";

function yo() {
    if (line == "yes") {
        return;   
    }
    else {
        window.alert("hi");
    }
}
```

Still, you can do better:

```
var line = "no";

function yo() {
    if (line !== "yes") {
        window.alert("hi");
    }
}
```